# Unable to round off decimal places using round() function

Tags: r

I am trying to round off the decimal places of all numbers in a column as follows:

```
data_frame$column1 %>% round(data_frame$column1,2)
```

Where `data_frame` is my data frame and `column1` is the name of the column which contains the numerical data with 6 decimal points which I'm trying to round off to 2 decimal places (I created the column1 by dividing two other columns in data_frame).
I'm getting an error:

```
Error in data_frame$column1%>%round(data_frame$column1,2) ,  : 
  3 arguments passed to 'round' which requires 1 or 2 arguments
```

What I understood is that, it's considering data_frame, column1 and 2 as 3 arguments in `round()` function. and when i just run the code `round(data_frame$column1,2)` I'm getting the correct decimal places that I want, but since its not passed to the desired column name, the data frame is not updated. I'm stuck here unable to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is (in short), you don't seem to understand how the pipe works in R. The pipe takes the output of something, and then sends it to the next function as the first argument.

For example, `1.2345 %>% round(2)` is equivalent to `round(1.2345, 2)` (Output is 1.23). Likewise, `data_frame$column1 %>% round(data_frame$column1, 2)` is equivalent to `round(data_frame$column1, data_frame$column1, 2)`. Seeing as `round()` takes two arguments, and you've given it three, it throws the *"3 arguments passed to 'round'"* error.

For more information, [read the documentation](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/index.html#overview).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. As a beginner, i understand that pipe takes output of one function and use it as argument for next. My problem is, if not round() what other function can i use to roundoff the decimal places?  or is there any other way to make the round() function to work so that it doesnt read it as round(data_frame$column1, data_frame$column1, 2)?   i do not have any experience with R and just started self learning few weeks ago.

Comment: I suppose there is probably *some* function which does it, but round() is the one you should use. You just need to give the function data_frame$column1 once, instead of twice... does that make sense?

Comment: "need to give the function data_frame$column1 once, instead of twice" i did not understand this part. i tried data_frame$column1 %>% round(column1, 2) which gave error column1 not found and when i tried data_frame %>% round(data_frame$column1, 2), my data frame turned to one which has only the column1 and other coloumns are deleted

Comment: @RLearner have you read the documentation? I don't know how much clearer I can be. The pipe turns the thing on the left into the first argument of the function on the right hand side. Listing it again on the right hand side is to give it the same argument twice

Comment: here's a tutorial on it: https://www.statology.org/pipe-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

`round(data_frame$column1, 2)` will round all values in column1 of the data_frame object, but it will just print the values (you have not assigned the answer to any object)

`data_frame$column1 %>% round(2)` does the exact same thing but with the pipe. As Mark stated, the pipe passes the data from in front of the pipe into the function following the pipe. So if data_frame$column1 is the data you want to modify and you will use pipe - then you must EXCLUDE the data from the round function.  However, this function alone will also only show you the answer - you have not modified the original data or created a new data object.

`data_frame$rounded <- data_frame$column1 %>% round(2)` would assign the new rounded values into a new column called rounded in your object called data_frame.  Alternatively, `data_frame$column1 <- data_frame$column1 %>% round(2)` would overwrite the original values with your new rounded values.